# Get Pre chat data in Einstein Bots

Tags: liveagent, einstein, pre-chat, bots, einstein-chatbot

I have a bot deployed using Embedded Service. I'm following Einstein Bots Developer Cookbook. 
In my PreChat form, I'm getting customer Name, which I want to use while greeting.

I have added below code in my website, to get details in Chat Transcript object:

```
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
  "label":"First Name",  
  "transcriptFields": ["FirstName__c"]
},{
  "label":"Last Name", 
  "transcriptFields": ["LastName__c"]
},{
  "label":"Email", 
  "transcriptFields": ["Email__c"]
}];
```

I'm extracting the transcript fields using Metadata API Solution.

I have also given the field permission in the sfdc.chatbot.service.permset permission set.

I can also see my chat transcript record is not getting created. I'm using Omni-channel queue-based routing.

Is there any other step which I'm missing?

Comment: Transcript record should be created. is it a customer website or embedded cloud site? For the later the snippet is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't completed the rest of the steps, step 5 and beyond. 
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_greet_customer_lex.htm

Comment: Yes, I did and I'm using the Metadata API Solution, to retrieve the firstname